# Converting a list of list into a dictionary based on common values in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of list in python as follows:

```
a = [['John', 24, 'teacher'],['Mary',23,'clerk'],['Vinny', 21, 'teacher'], ['Laura',32, 'clerk']]
```

The idea is to create a dict on the basis of their occupation as follows:

```
b = {'teacher': {'John_24': 'true', 'Vinny_21' 'true'},
     'clerk' : {'Mary_23': 'true', 'Laura_32' 'true'}}
```

What is the best way of achieving this ?

Comment: Why do you need a nested `dictionary`? Won't a `list` suffice like `{'teacher': ['John_24',  'Vinny_21'] }`

Comment: what i did was to loop through a and take a[2] and then create a dict using default dict from the collections module..however,then i had to again sort the dict to get the desired result..was looking for something more efficient

Comment: So you have a working solution and want to look to improve it... you might want to look at another stackexchange property [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) where these questions are better located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a defaultdict:

```
a = [['John', 24, 'teacher'],['Mary',23,'clerk'],['Vinny', 21, 'teacher'], ['Laura',32, 'clerk']]


from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(defaultdict)


for name, age, occ in a:
    dct[occ][name + "_" + age] = "true"
```

Output:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(dict(dct))
 {'clerk': defaultdict(None, {'Laura_32': 'true', 'Mary_23': 'true'}),
'teacher': defaultdict(None, {'John_24': 'true', 'Vinny_21': 'true'})}
```

Although you may be as well just appendiing each name to a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(list)

for name, _, occ in a:
    dct[occ].append(name + "_" + age)
```

Which woud give you:

```
 defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'clerk': ['Mary_23', 'Laura_32'], 'teacher': ['John_24', 'Vinny_21']})
```

If you want to use the age later you may also wan to store them separately:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(list)


for name, age, occ in a:
    dct[occ].append([name, age])
```

Which would give you:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'clerk': [['Mary', 23], ['Laura', 32]],
             'teacher': [['John', 24], ['Vinny', 21]]})
```

Using python3 you can use:

```
for *nm_age, occ in a:
    dct[occ].append(nm_age)
```

Comment: @Padraic..i don't think your output for the the first snippet of code is correct..it does not concatenate the name and age..the output i get is :           {'clerk': defaultdict(None, {'Laura': 'true', 'Mary': 'true'}),
 'teacher': defaultdict(None, {'John': 'true', 'Vinny': 'true'})}

Comment: @Amistad, yes, sorry, I edited it out somewhere along the line. It is fixed now

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can just use a list instead of a dictionary.

Here is one way to implement this:

```
a = [
    ['John', 24, 'teacher'],
    ['Mary', 23, 'clerk'],
    ['Vinny', 21, 'teacher'],
    ['Laura', 32, 'clerk'],
]

b = {}
for name, age, occupation in a:
    b.setdefault(occupation, []).append('{}_{}'.format(name, age))

print b  # {'clerk': ['Mary_23', 'Laura_32'], 'teacher': ['John_24', 'Vinny_21']}
```